# Mapstruct optional mapping

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

I am wondering how can i change this `mapping` using `mapstruct` to avoid nullPointer exception.
`rep.getClientLevelType()` can be null, or can be `DIRECT` or
    `RELATED`. When `fromValue` executes on `null` or `empty.string` null pointer exception occurs. 
   I don't know how to do that this field is only present if `rep.getClientLevelType()` is not null using `mapstruct`.

```
@Mapping(target = "clientLevelType", expression = "java(ClientLevelType.fromValue(rep.getClientLevelType()))")
```

enum document generated from wsdl:

```
@XmlType(name = "ClientLevelType")
@XmlEnum
public enum ClientLevelType {

    DIRECT,
    RELATED;

    public String value() {
        return name();
    }

    public static ClientLevelType fromValue(String v) {
        return valueOf(v);
    }    
}
```

`WSDL`:

```
   <xs:simpleType name="ClientLevelType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="DIRECT"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="RELATED"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: just check if `v` is `null` if so return `null`.

Comment: @M.Deinum How to change `wsdl` so it will generate `enum` that way?

Comment: @M.Deinum added wsdl fragment.

Comment: Hmm missed the generated part. Do you actually need the expression? The enum should be perfectly mappable from the incoming String... No need to call the `fromValue` AFAIK.

Comment: @M.Deinum yes - i do not want there `String` i want the type to be `ClientLevelType`.

Comment: I know you want that, but MapStruct will implicitly do the conversion. You don't need an expression for that. `String` to enum is an implicit conversion which is handled automatically by mapstruct. See http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#implicit-type-conversions

Comment: @M.Deinum you reccomend something like `source = "clientLevelType"` It will implicity convert to enum ?

Comment: exactly. You are basically making things overly complex by the expression.

Comment: @M.Deinum cool - make an answer so i can upvote and accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting a `String` to an `enum` can be done implicitly by mapstruct, see [implicit type conversions](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#implicit-type-conversions) in the documentation.

So instead of adding an `expression` simply add the `source` or when the names of the fields match you could even leave those out and MapStruct will then automatically detect the mapping.